# Peewee FlaskDB not accepting keyword arguments (eg. max_connections, stale_timeout)

Tags: python, python-3.x, peewee

The app I've been working on, which uses Python 3.9, Flask 2.0.2, peewee 3.14.4, and MySQL 8.0 works fine, except when I add configuration options for the FlaskDB dictionary of configuration options. I need to add MySQL configuration options (including SSL) when I deploy the app.

***The FlaskDB configuration options which do work***

```
    DATABASE = {
        'name': DB_NAME,
        'engine': 'peewee.MySQLDatabase',
        'user': DB_USERNAME,
        'passwd': DB_PASSWORD,
        'host': DB_HOST,
        'port': DB_PORT}
```

***The FlaskDB configuration options which do NOT work***

```
    DATABASE = {
        'name': DB_NAME,
        'engine': 'peewee.MySQLDatabase',
        'user': DB_USERNAME,
        'passwd': DB_PASSWORD,
        'host': DB_HOST,
        'port': DB_PORT,
        'max_connections': 32,
        'stale_timeout': 300}
```

***The error I receive from the uwsgi log***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/./wsgi.py", line 4, in <module>
    from run import app
  File "/app/./run.py", line 6, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "/app/./ticketsapi/__init__.py", line 33, in create_app
    from ticketsapi.users.routes import users
  File "/app/./ticketsapi/users/routes.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ticketsapi.models import User, Post
  File "/app/./ticketsapi/models.py", line 302, in <module>
    initalisedB()
  File "/app/./ticketsapi/models.py", line 233, in initalisedB
    if User.table_exists():
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/peewee.py", line 6658, in table_exists
    return cls._schema.database.table_exists(M.table.__name__, M.schema)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3310, in table_exists
    return table_name in self.get_tables(schema=schema)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/peewee.py", line 4011, in get_tables
    return [table for table, in self.execute_sql(query, ('VIEW',))]
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3142, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.cursor(commit)
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3126, in cursor
    self.connect()
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3080, in connect
    self._state.set_connection(self._connect())
  File "/app/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/peewee.py", line 3982, in _connect
    conn = mysql.connect(db=self.database, **self.connect_params)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_connections'
```

Looking at page 287 of the *peewee Documentation, Release 3.14.4* my syntax looks to be valid. From the peewee documentation:

```
    DATABASE = {
        'name': 'my_app_db',
        'engine': 'playhouse.pool.PooledPostgresqlDatabase',
        'user': 'postgres',
        'max_connections': 32,
        'stale_timeout': 600,
        }
```

Any thoughts on where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious answer, I needed to add `playhouse.pool.PooledMySQLDatabase` to the configuration options:

```
    DATABASE = {
        'name': DB_NAME,
        'engine': 'playhouse.pool.PooledMySQLDatabase',
        'user': DB_USERNAME,
        'passwd': DB_PASSWORD,
        'host': DB_HOST,
        'port': DB_PORT,
        'max_connections': 32,
        'stale_timeout': 300}
```